# Ack in a bash subshell

Tags: bash, ack

I want to search a number of files "in a bash loop".

Suppose I exec an ack search in a bash loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

seq 3 | while read i
do
    test=`ack root /etc/passwd`
    echo $test
done
```

prints one empty line.

Where as

```sh
#!/bin/bash

seq 3 | while read i
do
    # test=`ack root /etc/passwd`
    echo $test
done
```

prints 3 empty lines.

If I ran just that one command from the bash it works:

```sh
ack root /etc/passwd
```

This also works:

```sh
$ test=`ack root /etc/passwd`
$ echo $test
```

I think ack somehow breaks the loop.

Here's "the origin of the problem":

```bash
ls input/* | while read scan
do
    temp=`basename "$scan"`
    baseName=${temp%.*}
    extension=${temp#*.}

    # OCR:
    abbyyocr11 -rl Russian -if "$scan" -f TextUnicodeDefaults -of "temp/$baseName.txt"

    # get data:
    firstName=` ack '^Имя\s+(.+)'      --output='$1' "temp/$baseName.txt" | sed 's/ //g'`
    middleName=`ack '^Отчество\s+(.+)' --output='$1' "temp/$baseName.txt" | sed 's/ //g'`
    lastName=`  ack '^Фамилия\s+(.+)'  --output='$1' "temp/$baseName.txt" | sed 's/ //g'`

    # copy the file with a meaningful name:
    cp --backup=numbered "$scan" "output/$lastName$firstName$middleName.$extension"

done
```

**Edit**

Turns out `--nofilter` option solves it. According to `--help` message it forces ack treat stdin as tty as opposed to pipe. I wonder what this means.

Comment: You could make your edit a proper answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it doesn't like a pipe on stdin for some reason.
I don't know why it does that, but a quick and easy fix would be:

```
seq 3 | while read i
do
    test=`</dev/null ack root /etc/passwd`
    echo $test
done
```

or in your case

```
 # get data:
 {
     #....
 } </dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks. After reading your answer, I re-read the `--help` message and found out that `--nofilter` option works for my usecase.